# Error says that POST request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream even though I explicitly define it as such

Tags: javascript, forms, rest, groovy, gsp

I'm trying to implement a link in a Groovy server page that sends a POST request containing the text of the link they clicked on to another GSP, then load that page. I have tried several different solutions to this problem from other questions on StackOverflow, but every single one ends up raising a `org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is null` error. What's going on here? I'm also interested in different approaches for this.

Request:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/post.js"></script>
<a href="actions/manage.gsp" onclick="post('/actions/manage', {name: '${file}'});">${file}</a>
```

post.js:

```
function post(path, params, method) {
    method = method || "post";
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute('enctype','multipart/form-data').
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);

    for(var key in params) {
        if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

manage.gsp:

```
<%! static output = "text/html" %>
Testing!
<% log.info("Found ${request.parts.size()} parts") %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just typo remove dot after form.setAttribute('enctype','multipart/form-data');

```
function post(path, params, method) {
    method = method || "post";
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("enctype","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);

    for(var key in params) {
        if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

And speaking about the concept, i'd like to offer you this:

```
function post(path, params, method) {
 method = method || "post";
 var formData = new FormData();
 for(var key in params) {
        if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
           formData.append(key,params[key] );
        }
    }

        $.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: path,
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
            }).done(function( result ) { 
               //alert(result)  
            });
}
```

Comment: Good catch, but unfortunately the error's still there.

Comment: do you have errors in a console? try also text/plain

Comment: and can you prin out what in {name: '${file}'} probably it's related to the content of the ${file}

Comment: No console errors, text/plain doesn't work either. {name: '${file}'} is undefined when I try to print it.

Comment: put it first line in a function alert(params['name']) and what in a alert box ?

Comment: That worked! Looks like in order to get rid of the error I also had to change the link location. Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

I think you missed "input type=file" is missing.

Comment: I'm not POSTing a file though. It's just text.